# NGINX basic authentication based on environment variable

Tags: nginx, docker, lua, docker-compose, nginx-location

I'm setting up a docker image with nginx-lua installed. The scenario is to have a basic authentication on staging, but not in production. My idea was to have an ENV variable with the name of the stage and check the value in the nginx.conf file.

The content of the `docker-compose.yml` file (for staging, and for production the STAGE env will be `prod` of course):

```
docs-router:
  build: ./nginx 
  environment:
    - API_BASE_URI=staging.example.com
    - DOCS_STATIC_URI=docs-staging.example.com
    - STAGE=staging
  ports:
    - "8089:8089"
    - "8090:8090"
```

The content of the `nginx.conf` file:

```
...

env API_BASE_URI;
env DOCS_STATIC_URI;
env STAGE;

...

http {
  server {
    listen 8089 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    access_log off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location ~ ^(/.*\.(?:apib|svg))?$ {
      set_by_lua_block $api_base_uri { return os.getenv("API_BASE_URI") }
      set_by_lua_block $stage { return os.getenv("STAGE") }
      set $unprotected "prod";

      if ($stage = $unprotected) {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
      }

      proxy_pass https://$api_base_uri$1;
      proxy_set_header Host $api_base_uri;
    }

    ...

  }

}
```

But it's not working. Any idea, how can I achieve this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: This configuration is not working and I would like to know that my config is wrong, or this implementation is not going to work with NGINX.

Comment: My target is to have a single docker image with a proper NGINX configuration, which can be deployed at any stage and requests authentication only in a specific environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just find a solution with some help from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/761972/364901). It's not the best one because the URLs are in the `nginx.conf` file, but it solves my problem:

I just removed the variable form the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
docs-router:
  build: ./nginx 
  environment:
    - API_BASE_URI=staging.example.com
    - DOCS_STATIC_URI=docs-staging.example.com
  ports:
    - "8089:8089"
    - "8090:8090"
```

And then I mapped the URLs in the `nginx.conf` file:

```
...

env API_BASE_URI;
env DOCS_STATIC_URI;

...

http {

  ##
  # URL protection
  ##
  map $http_host $auth_type {
    default "off";
    stage1.example.com "Restricted";
    stage2.example.com "Restricted";
  }

  server {
    listen 8089 default_server;
    charset utf-8;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    access_log off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location ~ ^(/.*\.(?:apib|svg))?$ {
      set_by_lua_block $api_base_uri { return os.getenv("API_BASE_URI") }

      auth_basic $auth_type;
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

      proxy_pass https://$api_base_uri$1;
      proxy_set_header Host $api_base_uri;
    }

    ...

  }

}
```

If there is a better / nicer solution for this, please let me know.

Comment: I just came across with a little bit more complex solution. I define an environment variable like `RESTRICTED_STAGES` and include the hostnames which are needs to be protected (comma separated). During the docker build, I will parse this variable, read the hostnames and alter the original `nginx.conf` file with them - and now it's configurable.

Comment: I just accepted my own solutions because there wasn't any other idea, or suggestion.